# Can (or must) a nazir return a lost object found in a cemetery?

Tags: bava-metzia, nozir, lost-and-found

A Kohen may not perform the mitzvah of returning a lost object if it requires entering a cemetery. Bava Metzia 32a. What about a nazir? The nazir has two negative commandments (per sefer haChinuch) against becoming tamei meis, but no positive commandment to stay tahor/kadosh. So could (or even should) a nazir enter a cemetery to return a lost object?

Comment: Are you asking that for the nozir, the positive commandment of returning a lost object should push aside the negative commandments of not becoming tomei meis?

Comment: לא דחינן איסורא מקמי ממונא - Bava Metzia 30a

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - yes.

Comment: @שלום - is that enough to fully resolve the question? It is given as an additional explanation, almost an afterthought. Rambam doesn't allude to it when he discusses this scenario in Mishneh Torah.

Comment: Nazir has aseh of ככל היוצא מפיו יעשה (see Rambam Hilchot Nezirut 1:3)

Comment: @JoelK Interesting... that could work. Would love to see a source that ties it together that way. 

Separately, was just looking at Nazir 47a, where the chachamim conclude that a nazir should be metamei instead of even a regular kohen when the two of them come across an unburied body, because the nazir's restriction is temporary and not permanent. But of course burial is a ritual mitzva and not a money matter, to Shalom's comment earlier.

Comment: @PurpleTurtle check out Minchat Chinuch 539. He discusses this towards the beginning

Comment: No. Because the *mitzva* of *hashavas aveida* is a *mitzva* which is fulfilled by achieving the outcome of your actions, and not an inherent *mitzva*-action (see the piece on *Mitzvah ha'bah be'aveirah* in the latest edition of the Kol HaTorah).

Comment: @JoelK Thanks, I can see where the relevant material is I think but my Hebrew is not good enough to be confident in my translation/comprehension.

Comment: @PurpleTurtle the piece is quite involved and I haven't had the time to get a good grasp of exactly what he is saying. If I get a chance to learn it properly I'll bli neder write up an answer. In the meantime, if anyone else is able to do so then please go ahead and answer.